# Unable to delete rows from table based on condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to delete all records from second table based on the condition in first table. However Its not working. When I try to delete records without condition. it works fine and records are deleted. Dont know whats the issue

```
if(!is_null(Input::get('id'))) {
    $dates= DB::table('feedates')->where('feeCategory', '=', $ID)->count();

    if($dates == $freq) {
        $x = DB::table('feedates')->where('feeCategory', '=', $ID)->delete();
    } 
}
```

I am using php Laravel with mysql

Comment: What is $freq equal to and what is its relative code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as per authors comment: error was caused by another, unrelated bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()

```
Dim RowToTest As Long
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(RowToTest, 5)
        If .Value <> "Test" Then Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next RowToTest
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to do MYSQL operation in Laravel try to use tinker in shell script in cmd or IDE console it will definitely helps for your all queries. And also use save() function in your queries operation. I hope it will helps you.